# can't stop obsolete version of XML file from loading on web page

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have some generic javascript that loads and displays photos on an html page based on an xml file that it reads. The problem is that if I change the content of the xml file, it doesn't show up on the web page. Here's a section of an xml file to give you an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
<slides>
  <slide>
     <name>slideshow/cal2018/20180506.jpeg</name>
     <alt>some alt text</alt>
   ...
```

The problem that triggered my issue is I decided to move the "slideshow/" into the xml file instead of having it in the javascript. When I did that, the photos stopped showing up - I just got the alt text. However when I switched to a different page, the photos were brought up properly.

The problem is that all the web browsers seem to want to hold on to xml files for a long time - apparently at least a week, which is how long I worked on the pages without the current version of the xml file being loaded.

I can manually clear the browser cache and the problem resolves itself for that browser. Simply reloading the page, which is sufficient to reload the javascript, doesn't do that.

I use a lot of xml files to drive web pages. I need to ensure that the xml file is the current one and not some ancient cached copy. Is there a cross-browser (javascript?) way I can clear the (xml) cache before loading an xml file?

Also, why do browsers ignore xml files when I ask for a page reload?

Comment: Make sure you change the size of your xml file. For instance if you replace "3030.jpeg" for "2938.jpeg" the size is the same so it's less likely that it will be refreshed. Also, if you hit Ctrl+F5 it should reload everything.

Comment: The xml file did change size when I moved the "slideshow/" part of the path into each photo's path (the name element). I did some more changes later and it still refused to recognize that the file needed to be reloaded.

Comment: My concern isn't with my browser not loading the latest file. It's with every site visitor's browser not loading the updated file if they still have a cached copy of the old file. That's why I need a method for the page to force a reload of the file. My xml files vary in size from a few k to a little over 100k so downloading a fresh copy doesn't significantly slow the page down, but having outdated content is not acceptable.